# How to shift list indexes by a certain value in Python

Tags: python, indexing

I need to create a python function that right shifts values in a list by a given value.

For example if the list is [1,2,3,4] and the shift is 2 it will become [2,3,4,1]. the shift value must be a non negative integer. I can only use the len and range functions.

This is what I have so far

```
def shift(array, value):
    if value < 0:
        return
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        arr[i] = arr[(i + shift_amount) % len(arr)]
```

Comment: Why not just slice?

Comment: arbitrary restrictions? Sounds like homework

Comment: What is the problem with what you have now?

Comment: you need to create a new list, and  append to it.  You are overwriting your list

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can do this with slicing

```
arr = arr[shift:] + arr[:shift]
```

Your shifted list is only `shift = 1`, not 2. You can't get your output by shifting 2 positions.

Answer (score -1):

I make some modifications in your code (If you have to use `len` and `range` functions) :

```
def shift(array, shift_amount):
    if shift_amount < 0:
        return
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(array)): 
        ans.append(array[(i + shift_amount) % len(array)])
    print ans
shift([1,2,3,4],2)
```

Output:

```
[3, 4, 1, 2]
```

> **Note:**
>
> - Your's logic is correct but your overriding values in same array, So    I created another list and append value to it.
> - If shift value is 1 then output will be `[2, 3, 4, 1]`. So for value 2    it will be two shifts that's why output should be `[3, 4,
>     1, 2]`
> - value and shift_amount are two different variables in your code, So I    use only single variable.

You can use *list comprehension* (If you want to check in detail about *list comprehension* see this article [Python List Comprehensions: Explained Visually](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)) like

```
def shift(array, shift_amount):
    if shift_amount < 0:
        return
    length = len(array)
    print [array[(i + shift_amount) % length] for i in range(length)]
shift([1,2,3,4],0)
```